# Git Status Error color.ui

Tags: git

When I was setting up my SourceTree I met an annoying problem that it kept reminding me the following error:

git status
fatal: bad numeric config value 'purper' for 'color.ui': invalid unit

I'm a programming newbee and don't quite know how git works and how to solve this problem, can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: maybe this will help
https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-colours-in-git

Answer (score 1):

This command should fix it **`$ git config --global color.ui false`**

Answer (score 0):

`color.ui` does not understand the value "purper" (I suppose you mean "purple", but either way, it's not a valid value). The [valid values](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) are:

> false or never if you prefer Git commands not to use color unless enabled explicitly with some other configuration or the --color option; always if you want all output not intended for machine consumption to use color, [or] true or auto (this is the default since Git 1.8.4) if you want such output to use color when written to the terminal.

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't quite understand why i have such a problem, I never set up color.ui manually..