# How to reset color.ui?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I'm trying to use "Git status" on my test file and keep getting the error message

> "fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'color.ui': invalid unit
> charlespine@Charless-MacBook-Pro git_test %"

I have tried setting it to auto again, I have tried setting it to false but I don't know much about Git and have Googled everywhere.

UPDATE
I go into git config -list and i notice this

> color.ui=auto
> color.ui==

Don't know how i did that second one. Anyone know how to delete it?

Comment: I think your question would be better suited for superuser.

Comment: Did you attempt to edit the git output settings in some way?  Or this is what you are getting from your initial, unaltered installation of git?

Comment: @AlexanderNied yes i did, i was told to change the setting to true but then auto and i think i typed in something like git config color.ui = true

Comment: @evolutionxbox what is superuser? Sorry, I'm brand new.

Comment: @CharlesPine sorry it’s another stackexchange site. It’s better for command line stuff

Comment: @evolutionxbox No worries at all! I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797177/git-status-error-color-ui

Comment: How exactly have you tried to reset it?  Incidentally, you might just look at this post for fully resetting your git config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853986/easiest-way-to-reset-git-config-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally figured it out! I had to use

`git config --unset-all color.ui`

then reset it using

`git config --global color.ui auto`

Thank you to everyone who took the time to help out and suggest different solutions or suggestions. Feels so good to be able to figure it out finally. Happy coding! Thanks again everyone!